# Events not being sent to firebase analytics on the web

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-analytics

Firebase Version: `8.10.0`

Project: `Next JS with Typescript`

How am I sending:

```
const logClickEvent = useCallback(
  (eventName: string, eventParams?: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      analytics().logEvent(eventName, eventParams)
    }
  },
  []
)
```

What I receive using the Google Analytics Debugger:
[image: Event Log]

As you can see, the `Sending Request` link does get executed but I don't see the log on Debug view of firebase. Then, I click on the `Sending Request` link and it opens an empty page. After that, I see a log on the Debug view of firebase. What might be the issue here? Please help!!

This is how I integrated firebase in my Next JS project:
In `utils/firebase.ts`:

```
import "firebase/analytics"
import firebase from "firebase/app"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
const { analytics } = firebase

export { analytics }
```

In `_app.tsx`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    analytics()
  }
}, [)
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this only works in production, not in dev environment. I initialized analytics in my `_app.tsx` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      analytics()
    }
  }, [])
```

Then created a hook like this:

```
const useLogClickEvent = () => {
  const logClickEvent = useCallback(
    (eventName: string, eventParams?: { [key: string]: any }) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        analytics().logEvent(eventName, eventParams)
      }
    },
    []
  )

  return { logClickEvent }
}
```

Then, used the hook anywhere in my components by importing it like this:

```
const { logClickEvent } = useLogClickEvent()

<Button onClick={() => {
   logClickEvent("event_name", {
        property_name: "property_value",
      })
}}>
   Some Button
</Button>
```